# Как можно получить данные из встроеной в приложение sqlite из другого приложения?

Tags: java

Есть сервер в виде исполняемого jar файла, на который приходят данные и помещаются во встроенную БД sqlite.

Такой вопрос: а как можно другому приложению брать данные из его БД ?

Суть

- данные приходят через socket
- обрабатываются и добавляются в БД sqlite через запрос insert into
- задача моего приложения их туда помещать
- задача PHP их оттуда забирать

Comment: Как данные приходят на jar? Поднят Rest сервис в самом jar? Сокеты?

Comment: @Chubatiy добавил

Comment: @Chubatiy наверное мой вопрос должен звучать так как прописать путь к  sqlite если она находится в другой папке в приложение java ?

Comment: нет. Варианта у вас два(на мой взгляд): 1) Поднять Rest сервис на самом приложении. Желательно использовать JSON или XML для передачи данных 2) Ломиться по сокетам из php в jar. Возможно поможет статья: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714694/simple-java-tcp-server-and-php-client-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

другое приложение выполняет метод из 1-го приложения

```
  Data data = new org.first.src.data();
  data.getMyData();
```

Comment: А если оно на PHP подключение возможно ?

Comment: @VargSieg ну тогда нужно тебе напрямую юзать файл базы данных

Comment: Это как он же в jar ?

Comment: @VargSieg ну если в jar, то смотри мой ответ.

Comment: Как по вашему он с php вызовет код из 1-го приложения, написанного на java?

Comment: А если такой вариант вынести эту БД из jar в другую папку и и к ней будут обращаться все кому нужно ?

Comment: Во-первых: зачем БД в jar? Там реализовано API для работы с БД? Во-вторых: лучше сделать отдельный модуль DAO по управлению БД и через него работать с БД всеми сервисами(Это на тот случай, если такого API уже нет в вашем jar). Естественно реализовать Rest API в этом модуле.

Comment: А как тогда можно прописать адрес в моём приложение к ней ни как понять не могу `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:kod.sqlite");` ?

Comment: Опишите пож. в самом теле вопроса(сверху) что из себя представляет ваш JAR. Что у него имеется и как данные транслируются в БД(Через консоль, запросом и т.д.) А также уточните пож. вторую(php) часть модуля, который хочет что-то с данными делать